# Como usar o valor de saída

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como uso o valor de uma entrada depois que eu uso o botão `ok!`, pois preciso usar o valor da entrada que servirá como o raio, para poder fazer o calculo que será impresso dentro das outras duas `labels`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>area da esfera</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>


<style type="text/css">
    label{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>

<body>
        <label for="">Informe o raio</label><input type="text" name="raio">
        <button id="BUTTON" name = "button">OK!</button><br>        
        <label for "" >Área</label><input type="text" name="area" id = "circunferencia" disabled="" /><br>
        <label for "" >Volume</label><input type="text" name="circunferencia" id = "circunferencia" disabled="" /><br>

        <script>
            var buttons = document.getElementById("BUTTON");
            number entrada = document.getElementsByTagName("raio");
            document.getElementById("BUTTON").onclick = function() {
            number AreaEsf =  entrada * entrada  * 3.14; 
            number VolEsf  = (4/3) * 3.14 * entrada * entrada * entrada;  
            document.writeln(AreaEsf);
            document.writeln(VolEsf);
        }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias coisas que precisa de corrigir primeiro:

- `number entrada =` - Isso não existe. Para declarar uma variavel tem de usar uma das três possibilidades: `var`, `let` ou `const`.
- `entrada = document.getElementsByTagName("raio");` - O `<input>` que você quer ir buscar:

  ```
  <input type="text" name="raio">
  ```

  É uma etiqueta `<input>` e não `<raio>`, por esse motivo não iria funcionar com `getElementsByTagName`. Para além disso essa função devolve uma "lista" com todos os inputs que jogam com o nome passado, logo teria que indicar que quer o primeiro com `[0]`.
- `AreaEsf =  entrada * entrada  * 3.14;` - Assumindo que chegava ao `<input>` necessário, é necessário interpretar o seu valor com `.value` e ainda transformar em numero com `parseInt` antes sequer de o utilizar.
- A busca de `BUTTON` é feita duas vezes sem necessidade:

  ```
  var buttons = document.getElementById("BUTTON");
  ...
  document.getElementById("BUTTON").onclick = function() {
  ```

  Acabando por apenas complicar o código.

Haveria muitas outras coisas a melhorar, mas alterando apenas esses erros que eu indiquei, e deixando o código o mais parecido com o que tinha ficaria assim:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("BUTTON");

//getElementsByName em vez de ByTagName e a posição [0]
var entradaInput = document.getElementsByName("raio")[0];

buttons.onclick = function() { //utilizar o buttons de cima
    //interpretar o valor do input com .value e transformar em numero com parseInt
    var entrada = parseInt(entradaInput.value); 

    var AreaEsf =  entrada * entrada  * 3.14; //com var em vez de number
    var VolEsf  = (4/3) * 3.14 * entrada * entrada * entrada; //com var em vez de number
    document.writeln(AreaEsf);
    document.writeln(VolEsf);
}
```

Exemplo a funcionar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>area da esfera</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>


<style type="text/css">
    label{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>

<body>
        <label for="">Informe o raio</label><input type="text" name="raio">
        <button id="BUTTON" name = "button">OK!</button><br>        
        <label for "" >Área</label><input type="text" name="area" id = "circunferencia" disabled="" /><br>
        <label for "" >Volume</label><input type="text" name="circunferencia" id = "circunferencia" disabled="" /><br>

        <script>
            var buttons = document.getElementById("BUTTON");

            //getElementsByName em vez de ByTagName e a posição [0]
            var entradaInput = document.getElementsByName("raio")[0];

            buttons.onclick = function() { //utilizar o buttons de cima
                //interpretar o valor do input com .value e transformar em numero com parseInt
                var entrada = parseInt(entradaInput.value); 

                var AreaEsf =  entrada * entrada  * 3.14; //com var em vez de number
                var VolEsf  = (4/3) * 3.14 * entrada * entrada * entrada; //com var em vez de number
                document.writeln(AreaEsf);
                document.writeln(VolEsf);
            }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bastam poucas linhas de código javascript.**

> Basicamente, recupera o valor digitado, faz uma comparação se é um positivo, processa os cálculos e coloca os `values` nos devidos `inputs`

```js
function Calcular() {
//recupera valor digitado
var radius = document.getElementById('raio').value;
       
  if (0 < radius){
    var resultArea = document.getElementById("area").value = (radius * radius * Math.PI).toFixed(2);
    var resultCirc = document.getElementById("circunferencia").value = (2 * (Math.PI) * radius).toFixed(2);
    var resultVolume = document.getElementById("volume").value = ((4/3) * (Math.pow(radius, 3)) * (Math.PI)).toFixed(2);
  }else{
    alert("Erro - o raio deve ser um número inteiro maior que 0.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
  <label for="">Informe o raio</label>
  <input type="text" id="raio" size="10" />
  <br>
  <label for "" >Área</label> <input type="text" name="area" id="area" disabled="" /><br>
  <label for "" >Volume</label> <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" disabled="" /><br>
  <label for "" >Circunferência</label> <input type="text" name="circunferencia" id="circunferencia" disabled="" />
  <input type="button" value="OK!" onclick="Calcular()"/>
```

1. A função `Math.pow()` retorna a base elevada ao expoente, ou seja, base<sup>expoente</sup>

   - No exemplo do volume: raio<sup>3</sup>
2. `document.getElementById`, função javascript que serve para retornar um elemento do DOM que é identificado por um ID específico e que deve ser único
3. Em um controle HTML do tipo `textbox`, `password` ou uma `textarea`, poderemos utilizar a propriedade `value` que se refere ao valor do campo.

> Se não houver a necessidade de utilizar uma variável

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> poderemos , então, acessar diretamente:

```
document.getElementById("area").value = (radius * radius * Math.PI).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, dei uma mexida no teu código, vê se era isso que você estava querendo fazer.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('BUTTON');
var inputRaio = document.getElementById('raio')
var inputArea = document.getElementById('area')
var inputCircunferencia = document.getElementById('circunferencia')

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var raio = inputRaio.value;
    
    if (!raio.length) {
      alert('Por favor, insira um valor no raio');
      inputRaio.focus();
      return false;
    }

    inputArea.value = raio * raio * 3.14;
    inputCircunferencia.value = (4 / 3) * 3.14 * raio * raio * raio;
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    label{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<label for="">Informe o raio</label>
<input type="text" name="raio" id="raio"><br>

<label for="">Área</label>
<input type="text" name="area" id="area" disabled="" /><br>

<label for "" >Volume</label>
<input type="text" name="circunferencia" id="circunferencia" disabled="" /><br>

<button id="BUTTON" name="button" type="button">OK!</button><br>
```